# I changed display resolution and then back "illegal format on LG TV"

Tags: boot, xorg, wayland

I changed resolution from 1920x1080 60HZ to something else and got illegal format on the screen. I rebooted in Ubuntu Xorg, (which works), and changed the resolution back. It still get the invalid format on TV. I assume it is trying to use Waylen. I even reloaded a Timeshift snapshot to no avail. It is working fine as long as I set boot Ubuntu with Xorg in the circle at the login screen. Any ideas? A tegular monitor works fine any way I set the boot screen circle.

Ubuntu 21.04 Gnome 3.38.5
AMD Kabini Integrated APU
Now only Windows Server X11 satisfies TV No resolution settings seem work with Wayland now.
LG 50 inch TV - TV is complaining "Format ERROR" Not Ubuntu
Changed with Settings-->Display
Cant remember what it set to when it broke now 1280x720 (16:9) 59.9Hz was 1920x1080 (16:9) 60HZ
Everything works on normal Monitor oddly TV works also as second display with Wayland,

$ cat -n /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry
32  if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
33    menuentry_id_option="--id"
35    menuentry_id_option=""
38  export menuentry_id_option
150  menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-b117cc71-911a-42a2-b599-6283f1e9683f' {
167  submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-b117cc71-911a-42a2-b599-6283f1e9683f' {
168      menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-16-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.11.0-16-generic-advanced-b117cc71-911a-42a2-b599-6283f1e9683f' {
187      menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-16-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.11.0-16-generic-recovery-b117cc71-911a-42a2-b599-6283f1e9683f' {
205      menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-50-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-50-generic-advanced-b117cc71-911a-42a2-b599-6283f1e9683f' {
224      menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-50-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.8.0-50-generic-recovery-b117cc71-911a-42a2-b599-6283f1e9683f' {
254  menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
265  menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {

Comment: I'd suggest starting with your release details.... that way we know what software stack you're asking about...

Comment: And a better description of what you did... e.g.
1) How did you change resolution? Via settings -> Displays -> ...?
2) What is that "Something else"?
3) What is the exact message you got?
4) What is the device you are using as a monitor?
Plus, add the output of `cat -n /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep menuentry`